# My redux shopping cart wont show updated state of cart

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, shopping-cart

I am trying to create simple cart implementing react-redux. I am able to add item, remove item, change quantity of item in cart....it can be seen in my Navbar (where i have shopping cart item icon showing the count of items in current cart!). Also i have been tracking the changes with redux-dev tools...works as expected.

BUT,
when i click the CART icon in navbar to go to CART Page to view items, the cart ROLLBACKS to initial state.

For time being, i have two items in  cart as initial state....the cart page ALWAYS shows these items ONLY.

In my CART PAGE also I am able to change quantity of items being displayed or even remove them...

But only the products i added from proudct list page do not appear here....
seems like the state of cart RESET or is lost while I move to CART PAGE ACTUALLY..

I dont understand where did I go wrong

```
 index.js
       
    // initial state of cart
    const cart = {
      productsInCart: [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Mens Casual Premium Slim Fit T-Shirts ",
          "price": 22.3,
          "description": "Slim-fitting style,kline includes a three-button placket.",
          "category": "men's clothing",
          "image": "IMAGE SRC LINK",
          "rating": {
              "rate": 4.1,
              "count": 259
          }
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "WD 2TB Elements Portable External Hard Drive - USB 3.0 ",
        "price": 64,
        "description": "USB 3.0 andms;configuration and operating system",
        "category": "electronics",
        "image": "IMAGE SRC LINK",
        "rating": {
            "rate": 3.3,
            "count": 203
        }
    }
      
      ],
      cart:[{id:2, item_qty:3}, {id:9, item_qty: 2}], 
      totalItem:0,
      totalAmount:0
    }

// reducer for cart
export const cartReducer = (cartState = cart, action) => {
  
  // get payload
  const product = action.payload

  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_ITEM":    
      // check if product exist in cart already
      console.log('productsInState', cartState.productsInCart)
      const prodToAdd = cartState.productsInCart.find(item => item.id === product.id) 
      
      const itemExistInCart = cartState.cart.find(item=>item.id === product.id ? true : false)
      // update the state of cart by increasing amount
     
      cartState = {
        ...cartState,

        // add into product list if does not exist
        productsInCart : prodToAdd === undefined ?[ ...cartState.productsInCart,product]:[...cartState.productsInCart],
        
        // update only quantity in cart if already exist else add
        cart: itemExistInCart ? cartState.cart.map((item) => 
          (item.id === product.id )
          ?{
           
            ...item,
            item_qty: item.item_qty +  1 

          }  : item
        
        ) // if item does not exist in cart
        : [...cartState.cart, { id:product.id, item_qty:1}]
      }
 
       break;
    case "DELETE_ITEM":
      cartState = {
        ...cartState,
        productsInCart : cartState.productsInCart.filter(item=>item.id !== product.id),
        cart : cartState.cart.filter(item=>item.id !== product.id)
       
      };
      break;
    case "REDUCE_ITEM":
      console.log(action)
      cartState = {
        ...cartState,

        cart : cartState.cart.map((item) => 
        (item.id === product.id )
        ?{
         
          ...item,
          item_qty: item.item_qty >=1 ? item.item_qty -  1 : 1 

        } : item),            
      
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
console.log('updated state = ', cartState) // IT WORKS HERE AS WELL 
  return cartState
}
export const cartStore = createStore(cartReducer, composeWithDevTools( ))


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store = {cartStore}>
    <App />

    </Provider>
   
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))

reportWebVitals();


App.js 

    function App() {
     const state = useSelector(state=>state)
     console.log('appjs, state', state)
      return (
      
        <div className='container m-t-5'>
          
        <Navbar/> 
        <Home/>
    
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            
            <Route exact path="/products" element= {<Products/>}/>
            <Route exact path="/product/:id" element= {<ProductDetail/>}/>
            <Route exact path="/cart/" element= {<Cart cart = {state}/>}/>
           <!---I tried this also!!----Route exact path="/cart/" element= {<Cart/>}/--->
    
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    
        </div>
        
       
      );
    }
    
    export default App;

Navbar.js

    export const Navbar = (props) => {
        let qty = 0
        
        const [totalItemsInCart, setTotalItemsInCart] = useState(0)
         const state = useSelector((state) => state)
         useEffect(() => {
    
            state.cart.forEach(item => {
                qty += item.item_qty
                
            });
            setTotalItemsInCart(qty)
             console.log('posts', state.cart, 'total ', totalItemsInCart)
         }, [state])
    
        
        return (
           
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark p-2">
            
                <a className="btn btn-outline-light" href='/cart'>
                    <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart m-r-1"></i>
                Cart({totalItemsInCart})
                </a>     
           
          </nav>
           
        )
    }

CART.js


    export const Cart = (props) => {
        console.log('PROPS =>', props.cart) // I am getting initial state here also 
        const state = useSelector(state=>state) // I am getting initial state here also 
        const dispatch = useDispatch()
        const handleChangeItem = (val, item) => {
            if (val === "+") {
                dispatch({
                    type: "ADD_ITEM",
                    payload: item
                })
            }
            else if (val === "-") {
                dispatch({
                    type: "REDUCE_ITEM",
                    payload: item
                })
            }
            else {
                dispatch({
                    type: "DELETE_ITEM",
                    payload: item
                })
            }
    
        }
    
        const CartItems= ()=> state.productsInCart.map((item,id)=>{
            return(
                <div key={item.id}className="cart-card d-flex border">
                    <img className="cart-card__img" src={item.image} alt="" />
                    <div className="cart-item-detail">
                        <h5 className='display-7'>{item.title}</h5>
    
                        <p className='product-rating'>Rating: {item.rating.rate} </p>
                        <div className="qty_amount d-flex">
                            {
                                state.cart.map(prod => prod.id === item.id ?
                                    // prod.item_qty
                                    <>
                                         <div className="btn border" name="reduce" onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault();handleChangeItem("-", item)}}>-</div>
                                        <input type="number" min="1" value={prod.item_qty} className='item-qty border' />
                                        <div className="btn border m-r-1" name="add" onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault();handleChangeItem("+",item)}}>+</div>
                                        <h6 className='lead display-7'>Price : $ {item.price * prod.item_qty}</h6>
                                    </>
    
                                    : '')
                            }
                           
                        </div>
    
    
                        <div className="prod-buttons buttons d-flex">
                            <a className="btn btn-outline-dark "
                                href="/product/id">
                                <i className="fas fa-cart-plus m-r-1" /> details</a>
                            <a className="btn btn-outline-dark" onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); handleChangeItem("remove", item)}}>
                                <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart m-r-1" />Remove </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
       
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>Cart</h1>  
            {state.productsInCart.length > 0 ? (
                <>
                  <div className="container d-flex flex-column">
                   <CartItems/>
                </div>
                </>
                
    
    
            ):(<h1>empty cart</h1>)}  
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a normal anchor tag to navigate like `<a className="btn btn-outline-light" href='/cart'>` it's not using react router to navigate so it's like when you refresh the page. Your redux state is lost. You can use a `<Link>` from react router to naviagte, but i guess you want to store the state even when you refresh the page. For that you can use localstorage api or a database.

Comment: I just figured it out ... Thanks for your reply....

Comment: CASE CLOSED... :)